# Bootsrap menu alighn in center of page and responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, nav

If someone has time I'd like some help with a problem that I cant solve... 
I'm making a page for a local intermunicipal Football Association using Bootstrap. I want the page to also be fully mobile responsive...

So the problem I'm having is centering the menu/navbar (that yellow thing) to be alighned and have same width as the header (that blue thing)... 
It has to look like **this:** [image: **this**]

mine curenty looks like **this:** [image: **this**]

The blue thing has to be 106px high and the yellow thing has to be 40px high...

Oh and my code looks like this...

```css
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

#glava {
  height: 106px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #002d68;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffff01;
  color: #002d68;
  height: 40px;
}

.glavni-meni {
  background-color: #ffff01;
}

.header-seznam {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="glava">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="img/logo-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip" style="margin-top:12px; height:80px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <ul class="header-seznam">
            <li><img src="img/naslov.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
            <li><img src="img/telefon.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
            <li><img src="img/mail.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
            <li><img src="img/podatki.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid glavni-meni">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#mynavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Tekmovanja</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Klubi</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reprezentance</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Grassroots</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Klub Klubu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Obrazci in predpisi</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Trenerji in sodniki</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Delegati</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Razno</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ugodnosti</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S I apologize for bad english... not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to center navbar items.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li class="social pull-right"><a href="#">Social Links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to work.. just a quick question.. how do i hide the "<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>" when weived on a computer screen... i want it to show only on mobile

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

HTML:

```
<header id="glava">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="img/logo-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip" style="margin-top:12px; height:80px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <ul class="header-seznam">
            <li><img src="img/naslov.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
            <li><img src="img/telefon.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
            <li><img src="img/mail.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
            <li><img src="img/podatki.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="logotip"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-centered">
  <div class="container-fluid glavni-meni">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#mynavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Tekmovanja</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Klubi</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reprezentance</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Grassroots</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Klub Klubu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Obrazci in predpisi</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Trenerji in sodniki</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Delegati</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Razno</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ugodnosti</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

#glava {
  height: 106px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #002d68;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffff01;
  color: #002d68;
  height: 40px;
}

.glavni-meni {
  background-color: #ffff01;
}

.header-seznam {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-centered .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-centered .navbar-nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-centered .nav > li {
        display: inline;
    }
    .navbar-centered .nav > li > a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, now the content of nav is center alighned but now the dropdown doesent work when the page is displayed on a mobile device...